# wordpress: cant get category id when SEO URL is turned on

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Members
*/

   function myFilter2($query) 
    {

        if ($query->is_category)
        {
            $currently_listing_categories = $query->query_vars['category__in'];             
            print_r($currently_listing_categories);
        }

    }

    add_filter('pre_get_posts','myFilter2');
?>
```

This plugin display the category ids when the url is not SEO friendly

> http://domain.com/wplab/wpla4/?cat=4

. but when I turn on SEO

> http://domain.com/wplab/wpla4/category/members/

the array is empty

how can I get the category id with SEO friendly urls

Comment: You may want to consider removing your previous post [wordpress : category id and post id not getting when I change permanent link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358432/wordpress-category-id-and-post-id-not-getting-when-i-change-permanent-link). Or even better you may want to move it to the specialised [Wordpress Site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function to  get current cateogry in wp :

```
function getCurrentCatID(){

 global $wp_query;
 if(is_category() || is_single()){
  $cat_ID = get_query_var('cat');
 }
 return $cat_ID;
```

}

```
echo getCurrentCatID();
```

Just found for you also try this,

```
if(isset($wp_query->get_queried_object()->cat_ID))
{
    $cur_catId = $wp_query->get_queried_object()->cat_ID;
}
if(isset($wp_query->get_queried_object()->ID))
{
    $cur_postId = $wp_query->get_queried_object()->ID;
}
```

Comment: And call the function in your **template file**

Comment: @john - Are you getting current post_id there ?

Comment: no, but I get both post_id and category_id when I set SEO urls turned off

Comment: $cur_catId is working but $cur_postId is not working, please help

Comment: @john - Sorry, in my if condition change `issset` to `isset`...was a typo !!

Comment: cur_postId = $wp_query->get_queried_object()->ID; is always null

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13502/discussion-between-rikesh-shah-and-john-k)

Answer (score 0):

Paste in your `functions.php` or use in your plugin

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts','myFilter2');
function myFilter2()
{
    global $wp_query;
    $cat_name= $wp_query->query_vars['name'];
    $cat_id=get_cat_id($cat_name);
    echo $cat_id; // the category id will be available, echo is for testing only
}
```

When url is like `http://example.com/category_name`

[image]

Comment: It's been tested in my localhost.